# Nonabelian Hodge structure for noncompact curves and Hodge structure on the fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fundamental-group, connections, hodge-structure

Nonabelian Hodge theory, introduced by C. Simpson and others, may be interpreted as a description of the (real) Hodge structure on the fundamental group (say, of a compact curve) in terms of some moduli spaces, that correspond to Betti and de Rham cohomologies. For a compact curve (as far as I understand), this construction indeed gives a mixed Hodge structure on the formal functions near a trivial connection coming from the one on the fundamental group.

For noncompact curves, corresponding moduli spaces are described in 
["Harmonic bundles on noncompact curves"](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1990-03-03/S0894-0347-1990-1040197-8/) by C.Simpson. Is there any explanation, why this definition is the right one? Is it possible to extract from this structure some information about the fundamental group of the noncompact curves? Say, for a projective line with punctures?